# Log internet uptime on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm new here but I hope you guys (and girls?) can help me with following problem:

I manage a Windows Server 2012 machine (hosted at Hetzner.de). Over night, I need to run several tasks to transfer backup files and other stuff, like updated product data etc.

Now, since about 2 weeks it seems like our server loses his internet connection multiple times every night, for several minutes each time. Some of the transfer processes don't have the ability to resume their up-/downloads after this (can't change those because they don't actually run on our servers).

Our hoster tells there is no general internet access problem in the data center. For this, I need to find a way to log the actual internet accessability (not only the network connection logging Microsoft provides, but "full" internet access like the availability of a specific server).

If you got any further questions, I'll do my best to answer them in time.

Thank you very much in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the ping command to test the connectivity with google.
Windows ping command does not provide a timestamp. However, you may find this batch useful, as it provides a timestamp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906268/ping-with-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

For you case I will choose [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com)

With a free account on this free uptime monitoring service, you can monitor up to 50 nodes. If the problem still persists, it sends alert via email, SMS etc..

monitoring services are:

- ping
- open port monitoring
- http/https

If you need more advance solutons then use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

It is a full-scale network- and system-monitoring tool that combines several functions into a single Web-based console. It can be configured to monitor and collect data from a wide variety of servers and network gear, offering service and performance monitoring of each object.

Comment: I'll try those if the "Ping with timestamp"-answer is not enough ;)